# Bash script which adds a line before every curly brackets in PHP code

Tags: php, bash, sed, find

I need to create a bash script that adds a row before every  curly bracket for functions, classes (classes and methods) and try/catch blocks

I think using the program in conjunction with sed E.G.:

```
*find . -type f \( -name "*.php \) -exec sed .......*
```

For example:

```
<?php
function my_function() {

}
?>
```

Becomes:

```
<?php
function my_function() 
{

}
?>
```

Comment: What about curly brackets that are inside quotes?  Is it okay if they get a newline in front of them too?  And do you care about indenting?

Comment: And does http://beta.phpformatter.com/ help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU find` and `GNU sed`. It works for functions and classes. You can adjust accordingly to fix other blocks of your choosing. This solution also maintains leading whitespace, which you may find helpful.

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -r -i 's/( *)(function.*|classes.*)\{/\1\2\n\1\{/' {} \;
```

Comment: And for the try/catch blocks?

Comment: Easy. Simply change `(function.*|classes.*)` to `(function.*|classes.*|try.*|catch.*)`

Comment: I'll give this a +1 because it answers the question ... though I'm not entirely sure this question *should* be answered....

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -E $'s/ *{$/\\\n{/' -i {} \;
```

Replaces `*{` at the end of the line with a newline and a `{`.

If you're only doing certain curly braces (functions, classes, try/catch) but not others (if, while, etc.) then shell scripting is likely to prove inadequate.